# How can we look into the codes behind Power BI and learn and add features to it?

Tags: dax, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and I love its features, above all that it makes all the data light and hence easy to play around even on the phone.
I want to learn to add more visuals to the existing Power BI architecture. Where can I find resources to learn the code and hence implement or add upon the Power BI tool?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://powerbi.microsoft.com/developers for that info.

But first check the gallery of visuals submitted by the community - to avoid reinventing the wheel ...

https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/